# Javascript - Iterate over string and drop words from the end

Tags: javascript

Say I have a string `user.schedule.template.edit` and I want to iterate backwards through the string, separated by the `.` and so get the following results:

```
user.schedule.template.edit
user.schedule.template
user.schedule
user
```

What's the best way to do it? Is there a specific function for this, or should I just `.split()` and merge the strings?

Comment: I don't think it's any more complicated than using split() and then a for loop that counts down (i--) instead of the typical counting up (i++).

Comment: You could also iterate, using `.lastIndexOf` and `.substring`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it, but:

```
var words = "user.schedule.template.edit".split('.');
while(words.length) {
    console.log(words.join('.'));
    words.pop();
}
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jk4Uh/).